# Can you differentiate between Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2?

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

My use-case for what I'm after: what I'm aiming to achieve is the ability to silently deploy PowerShell 5 only to workstations via automation, I need to be able to prevent my deployment from hitting servers so that I don't cause the world to spontaneously collapse upon itself.

I'm currently using the following code to grab power shell version

```
$BuildVersion = [System.Environment]::OSVersion.Version
Write-Host($BuildVersion)
```

and using

```
if ($BuildVersion.Major -le '6')
```

To rule out any machines not running at-least 7 but I've found that I'm going to have an issue as both Windows 7 and Windows Server 2008 R2 have the same major build number.

My first thought was to change the code to only allow specific build numbers

But a bit of googling led me to find that 7 and 2008 R2 share the same build number 6.1.7601.

What I'm wondering is if there's some alternative method within PowerShell 2.0 of identifying Windows builds that would meet my needs.

I've had a look around stack overflow and can't find anything that directly resolves my issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Query the [`Win32_OperatingSystem` class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394239(v=vs.85).aspx). One of its attributes is the `ProductType` value. `1` means Client (ie. Windows 7), `2` means Domain Controller and `3` means Server (both Windows Server 2008 R2).

For the version, the `[System.Version]` type is ordinally comparable, so you don't have to inspect both the `Major` and `Minor` version (`$BuildVersion.Major -eq 6` would include both Vista and 7)

```
# Define a minimum version (Win7 family pre-release build)
$MinimumVersion = [version]'6.1'

# Fetch ProductType from WMI
$OSType = (Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_OperatingSystem -Property ProductType).ProductType

if($OSType -eq 1 -and [Environment]::Version -ge $MinimumVersion){
    # client OS, 7 or newer
}
```